# Calculated Column 48 hours due date weekday

Tags: calculated-column

I am trying to generate a simple calculated column formula for a 48 hours email alert considering weekdays only. No weekends. New at this. Any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a quick check to see if the alert date (+2 for 48 hours) will be on a Sunday (1). If so, then you return a date +3 to get the next Monday. Otherwise, if the alert date is Saturday (7), you return a date +4 to get the next Monday. If neither of those are true, then you can simply return the date +2:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(MyDate+2)=1,MyDate+3,IF(WEEKDAY(MyDate+2)=7,MyDate+4,MyDate+2))
```

You can easily swap out the MyDate field above with Modified or Created as needed. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. It did worked/helped.

Comment: Need additional help with calculation. I am trying to calculate now 24 hours and 5 days alert (WEEKDAYS). Please, assist. I am trying the formula above but stuck. Please note. It works fine as intended for the 48 hrs alert.

Comment: 24 Hours working with this =IF(WEEKDAY(MyDate+1)=1,MyDate+2,IF(WEEKDAY(MyDate+1)=7,MyDate+3,MyDate+2)) but not when day is SAT/SUN. So I would need to add a the part when IF SUN/SAT for a 24/48 Hours return.